# Customer enter directly to day 10 rather than going through day 1,2,5

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I would like to know, if it is possible for a customer to enter the journey at later date and continue the journey from that day.

Example - I am going live today, my journey is scheduled from Day 1, day 2, day 7, day 15, etc upto Day 365.

I am querying the data in such a way I identify the customers who has joined today and enters the journey and receives the day 1 email and goes upto 365.

How can I send an email from Journey Builder to the customer who has made purchase on last week (today is day 7).

Comment: so the customer in your example should receive the day 7 email ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t set up your journey to have paths that can go into day 7, there’s no way to inject them directly into day 7. You’ll need to either use data attributes and a Decision Split to put them there.

For example, if you have a column name with day and a numerical value of 7. Then at the beginning of the journey have a Decision Split that puts them before the email for day 7.

Alternatively, you can use the [Wait By Attribute](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_wait_for_a_date_based_on_an_attribute_value.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) split and date values. The use queries to populate that data.